# How to read the spark_df as dataframe in synapse analytics (Microsoft azure)?

Tags: python, azure, azure-synapse

How to read the spark_df as data frame in synapse analytics (Microsoft azure) so that i can use the necessary codes of pandas in the notebook?

```
spark_df = spark.createDataFrame(filtered_df)
spark_df.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("default.NYC_Taxi")
```

Now i want to read the table as dataframe. I tried the below code:

```
new_df = NYC_Taxi.to_pandas_dataframe()
```

Error:

```
NameError : name 'nyc_taxi' is not defined
Traceback (most recent call last):
NameError: name 'nyc_taxi' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the code like this:

```
spark_df = spark.createDataFrame(filtered_df)

new_df = spark_df.select("*").toPandas()
```